# Silverlight doesn't work on different IP segments of the Network

Tags: c#, silverlight, networking, ip

I have a Silverlight application that cannot login when it installed in a different IP Segment to the server. (The client is in 192.168.77.xx and the server is in 192.168.40.xx).

When the client is on the same segment it runs smoothly.

The client can ping, telnet and remote-desktop the server. It also can login other applications from the server, but it cannot login into my Silverlight application.

Does anybody know how to run Silverlight application with different IP Segments?

Comment: What exception are you getting ? Are you using web services for your authentification ? a bit more details pls.

Comment: Im getting nothing, yes Im using web services for authentication, using REST POST, and the authentication request is not in log of my application.

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)asynchResult.AsyncState;
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchResult);

I try catch the code above, and it is exception, and I also try using GET but it also fails.^^

Comment: @Stainedart, Im sorry I newly understand your question: here is the exception: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer] Arguments: NotFound Debugging resource strings are unavailable. OFten the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. etc

Comment: That exception is exist in one of client, it still throws exception although in the same IP Segment, while the problem of different IP Segment already solved by adding ClientAccessPolicy.xml in the root of the app server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent cross-site request forgery, Silverlight 4 (and later) allows only site-of-origin communication by default for all requests other than images and media. To enable a Silverlight control to access a service in another domain, the service must explicitly opt-in to allow cross-domain access.

So, you should place `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` or `CrossDomain.xml` at the root of web site where Silverlight application is hosted.

Here is sample of `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` (allows access from any other domain to all resources on the current domain):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

And here is sample of `CrossDomain.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) about making a service available across domain boundaries.

Comment: Do not use both ClientAccessPolicy.xml AND CrossDomain.xml. ClientAccessPolicy.xml has more features. CrossDomain.xml is allowed for only as a compatibility feature as it already exists on some Flash websites.

Comment: Thank you lazyberezovsky and HiTechMagic, I will add the code and test in the client office this day, because I still at home right now.

Comment: Is clientaccesspolicy.xml I should put on server side? I use java for the server and tomcat, where should I put the file? Thank you

Comment: @ImamBaihaqi Yes, on server side. To the root of your server. This is simple xml file, so there is no difference what technology used on server

Comment: @Lazyberezovsky, thank you so much, I put the ClientAccessPolicy.xml into folder tomcat/webapps/root and now it works, I can login from different IP segment

Comment: Btw, do you know why in other machine my application doesn't work? is there any software that I need to install to run Silverlight application? I already install Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile and the Extended, but still cannot run (actually this is different from the problem of different IP Segment). Thank you very much

Comment: You need only Silverlight plugin to be installed on client computer

Comment: What plug in lazyberezovsky? I already install dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe, thank you again for your attention^^